# Opening a Workspace causes python.pythonPath to be ignored

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

**Problem**

VS Code refuses to use the custom `python.pythonPath` I have specified in `settings.json` to run Python files through [Microsoft's Python Extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python). This only occurs when I open a workspace. Opening individual files is fine.

**Expected Solution**

Even when opening a workspace, the `python.pythonPath` variable should be respected and used instead of whatever the `Python: Select Interpreter` command or respective button (in the bottom-left) says.

**Further Explanation**

For background, the `A:\` drive is a portable driver that has many school-related files, including the Python Installation, VS Code Installation and the Python project's scripts I'm running.

When I open a workspace I use for a project I'm working on, I suddenly am forced into using a Python Interpreter other than what I have specified in `settings.json`.

Attempting to set one in the workspace settings file by copying the `python.pythonPath` line doesn't exhibit anything like the solution I need.
How can I get VS Code's Python extension to respect this setting, or if not possible, how can I set it (in the workspace settings) to also use the same extension I have specified.

---

**Directory for my Python Project** `A:\Programming\Python\Projects\Project Name\`
*(contains `workspace.code-workspace` file, as well as all scripts being ran)*

**Directory of the Python Installation** `A:\Installations\WinPython 64\python-3.6.6.amd64\`
*(python.exe is located within here)*

**Directory of the VS Code x64 Portable Installation** `A:\Installations\Visual Studio Code x64\`
*(Code.exe is located within here)*

---

**settings.json** - [full file](https://hastebin.com/ideciyicim.json)

```
{
    python.pythonPath": "A:\\Installations\\WinPython 64\\python-3.6.6.amd64\\python.exe",
    ...
    "python.jediEnabled": false
}
```

---

**workspace.code-workspace**

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.pythonPath": "A:\\Installations\\WinPython 64\\python-3.6.6.amd64\\python.exe"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> ... the python.pythonPath variable should be respected and used instead of whatever the Python: Select Interpreter command or respective button (in the bottom-left) says.

But `python.pythonPath` is what is actually set when you run `Python: Select Interpreter` or click on the interpreter in the status bar, and its value is what ends up being shown in the status bar. There isn't a way to have a different value in `python.pythonPath` compared to what is shown in the status bar.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does seem possible. [Screenshot of the impossibility](https://i.imgur.com/2J31i4g.png)

Comment: That screenshot is only showing your user settings. Please check what settings you have in your workspace and folder.

Comment: [I'm not sure how these are supposed to be formatted, but here was my best guess.](https://hastebin.com/yedaqamodu.json)

Comment: Unfortunately that pastebin link didn't have anything in it. Feel free to file a bug report, but please make sure to include the `settings.json` file for your install, your workspace, and the folder in the workspace.

Comment: FWIW, VS Code 1.51.1 and `ms-python.python` 2020.6.90262 does *not* set `python.pythonPath` when I change the interpreter.

Comment: @kynan yes, that's a change that started to role out this month.